# Covariant derivative in $f(Q,T)$ field equations

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, differential-geometry, differentiation, curvature

I am trying to evaluate the field equations in $f(Q,T)$-gravity and I'm not sure how to evaluate this term:

$$-\dfrac{-2}{\sqrt{-g}}\nabla_{\alpha}(f_{Q} \sqrt{-g}\enspace P^{\alpha}_{\enspace \mu \nu})$$

where $f_{Q}$ is the differential with respect to $Q$ of the chosen function, $\sqrt{-g}$ is the determinant of the metric tensor and $P^{\alpha}_{\enspace \mu \nu}$ is the superpotential tensor.

I want to evaluate this term on Mathematica and I'm having difficulty expand the covariant derivative. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

I am making reference to this paper:

- Y. Xu, G. Li, T. Harko, and S-D. Liang, "$f(Q,T)$ gravity", [Eur. Phys. J. C **79**, 708 (2019)](https://doi.org/10.1140/epjc/s10052-019-7207-4), [arXiv:1908.04760](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.04760). Specifically equation 31.

Comment: If you're trying to evaluate it with xAct then someone might answer you here: https://groups.google.com/g/xact?pli=1

Comment: I have never used xAct but I have heard of it